# Modifying multiple nonlocal variables using parameters inside a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

While attempting to create a simple message encrypting code in Python (3.6.3), I encountered a problem, which can be observed in the following code (separate test file):

```
import sys


def test(integ):
    integ += 1
    return


def main():
    x = 0
    y = 2
    test(x)
    test(y)
    print("{}\n{}".format(x, y))
    test(x)
    print(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, my goal is for it to give me 1, 3 and 2 in that order as an output, but it gives me 0, 2 and 0, meaning that the variables `x` and `y` aren't modified at all. So, after looking up possible solutions to my issue, I found the statement `nonlocal` and attempted to alter my code in the following way:

```
def test(integ):
    nonlocal integ
    integ += 1
    return
```

However, this time I obtain the following error: `SyntaxError: name 'integ' is parameter and nonlocal`, which leads me to the conclusion that I can not alter the variables `x` and `y` using a parameter within the function `test()`.

Would there be some sort of workaround for this issue while avoiding the use of global variables?

Comment: That's not how variables work in Python. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: If you are already calling `test(smth)`, why not return the new value and simply reassign `smth = test(smth)`?

Comment: `nonlocal` isn't what you want here. Python integers are immutable, you can't change them. Your `test` function needs to create a new integer object with the value you want and then return that new object to the calling code, by using the `return` statement.

Comment: @grovina The reason why I don't do it is because I wish to reuse the same function multiple times without having to reassign it manually every single time. This is especially bothersome if I wish to do it for multiple variables (say, not just 2 like in this example, but maybe 30 different ones). Having a simple solution would be more beneficial.

The second solution Brett suggested solved my issue thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

`test` just receives the value you're passing in, not a reference to the variable. An easy solution would be to reassign a return value:

```
>>> def test(integ):
...     return integ + 1
...
>>> x = 0
>>> x = test(x)
>>> x
1
```

If you want to return more than one value this way, the Pythonic way is through a tuple (which Python will pack/unpack for you, as shown):

```
>>> def test(integ):
...     return integ + 1, integ - 1 # same as `return (integ + 1, integ - 1)`
...
>>> test(0)
(1, -1)
>>> x = 0
>>> x, z = test(x) # same as `(x, z) = test(x)`
>>> x
1
>>> z
-1
```

Another option would be to wrap the value in something mutable (like a dictionary):

```
>>> def test(integ):
...     integ['value'] += 1
...     return
...
>>> x = {'value': 0}
>>> test(x)
>>> x['value']
1
```

Comment: First off, thank you for the quick reply. However, I have another question regarding the first method you proposed. Would there be a way for test(integ) to return two separate values? Or would it be more favorable to rely on the second method you proposed in that case?

Comment: Python makes it really easy to return more than one value. I added an example below the first method.

Answer (score 1):

same workaround technique (see Brett answer) with a list instead:

```
>>> def f1(a_mutable_var):
...     a_mutable_var[0] += 1
... 
>>> L1 = [1]
>>> f1(L1)
>>> L1
[2]
>>>
```